# Select Avançado separado por hora

Tags: php, mysql, sql, banco-de-dados, select

Montei um `SELECT` para retornar algumas informações da minha tabela separado por hora e data. Até essa parte está tudo funcionando corretamente. Agora preciso que ele selecione os mesmo dados só que de outra data, sendo que é a mesma tabela.

Meu `SELECT`:

```
SELECT  CONCAT('2015-07-27 ', Horas.Hora, ':00:00') as HORA, qtd_clique as CLIQUES, qtd_ligacoes as LIGACOES, qtd_form as FORM
FROM (
  SELECT '08' Hora UNION SELECT '09' UNION SELECT '10' UNION SELECT '11' UNION
    SELECT '12' UNION SELECT '13' UNION SELECT '14' UNION  SELECT '15' UNION
    SELECT '16' UNION SELECT '17' UNION SELECT '18' 
) Horas
LEFT JOIN relatorio_cliques C
    ON SUBSTRING(C.data_hora, 12, 2) = Horas.Hora
        AND C.data_hora LIKE '2015-07-27%' 
        AND C.cliente = 'cliente_teste'
GROUP BY CONCAT('2015-07-27 ', Horas.Hora, ':00:00')
ORDER BY 1;
```

O retro é desta foram:

```
HORA | CLIQUES | LIGACOES | FORM
```

Tenho as 3 colunar CLIQUES, LIGACOES e FORM da data 2015-07-27, agora precisaria das mesmas informações só que do dia 2015-07-26, por exemplo.

O retorno seria algo desta forma:

```
HORA | CLIQUES(27-07) | CLIQUES(26-07) | LIGACOES(27-07) | LIGACOES(26-07) | FORM (27-07) | FORM (26-07)
```

Tentei mas não consegui, se alguém poder ajudar ficar muito grato.

Comment: Verifique essa resposta que deve te ajudar

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14834290/mysql-query-to-dynamically-convert-rows-to-columns

Comment: é impressão minha ou esta duplicado ?/?http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/92276/otimiza%C3%A7%C3%A3o-de-consulta-sql-no-mysql-e-index/93925?noredirect=1#comment190439_93925

Comment: @MarconcilioSouza Isso foi quando montei a `QUERY` a quele é a otimização. Afinal isso é de 2 meses atrás.