# Otimização de Consulta SQL no MySQL e Index

Tags: php, mysql, sql, mysqli, otimização

Pessoal estou com um problema de desempenho em uma consulta `SQL` no `MySQL` que está utilizando muito meu servidor, já fiz `index` e mesmo assim o consumo não diminui.
A consulta que estou utilizando é:

```
SELECT
    CONCAT(
        '2015-10-14 ',
        Horas.Hora,
        ':00:00'
    ) AS HORA,
    COUNT(ID_CONTATO) AS TOTAL_GERAL
FROM
    (
        SELECT '00' Hora  UNION SELECT '01' UNION SELECT '02'
        UNION SELECT '03' UNION SELECT '04' UNION SELECT '05'
        UNION SELECT '06' UNION SELECT '07' UNION SELECT '08'
        UNION SELECT '09' UNION SELECT '10' UNION SELECT '11'
        UNION SELECT '12' UNION SELECT '13' UNION SELECT '14'
        UNION SELECT '15' UNION SELECT '16' UNION SELECT '17'
        UNION SELECT '18' UNION SELECT '19' UNION SELECT '20'
        UNION SELECT '21' UNION SELECT '22' UNION SELECT '23'
    ) Horas
LEFT JOIN CONTATO D ON SUBSTRING(D.CONTATO_DATA, 12, 2) = Horas.Hora
AND D.CONTATO_DATA LIKE '2015-10-14%'
AND CONTATO_CEP_BLOQUEADO IS NULL
GROUP BY
    CONCAT(
        '2015-10-14',
        Horas.Hora,
        ':00:00'
    )
ORDER BY 1
```

Tenho `325.000 registros` nesta tabela e essa consulta está levando em média `7 segundos`.

Fiz `index` em todas as colunas utilizadas e não mudou nada o tempo de retorno. Se alguém souber alguma otimização que eu possa fazer seria de muita ajuda. Obrigado.

Segue o `EXPLAIN` do resultado:
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/c034e/1/0

Comment: 7 segundos com o servidor em funcionamento ou apenas com esta query, e você vai executá-la mais ou menos uma vez por dia, hora, minuto ?

Comment: Em funcionamento, de 5 em 5 minutos.

Comment: Você pode colocar um `EXPLAIN` antes do `SELECT`, executar e incluir o resultado na pergunta? Obrigado.

Comment: Não sei de MySQL, mas não é possível fazer `GROUP BY 1` ?

Comment: @bfavaretto já incluí o `EXPLAIN` na pergunta, da uma olhada, obrigado.

Comment: elimina os pontos e testa com a tabela modificada para InnoDB ou MyISAM e compare a performance.

Answer (score 2):

Seu problema está nos pontos em que voce usa a função `CONCAT` e `SUBSTRING`. Quando você usa esse tipo de função como filtro de pesquisa ou funcao de agrupamento, o Banco de dados não consegue utilizar os indices para suas queries e precisa fazer o `TABLESCAN` completo toda vez.

Ajuste a sua query para não utilizar essas funções e você verá uma melhora de performance significativa.

Answer (score 0):

Veja se a consulta abaixo ajuda.

```
select D.HORA, COUNT(D.idBalanceteVersao) AS TOTAL_GERAL from
(
    SELECT  '2015-10-14 '+ Horas.Hora +':00:00'  AS HORA, idBalanceteVersao
    FROM 
    (
        SELECT '00' as Hora UNION SELECT '01' UNION SELECT '02'
        UNION SELECT '03' UNION SELECT '04' UNION SELECT '05'
        UNION SELECT '06' UNION SELECT '07' UNION SELECT '08'
        UNION SELECT '09' UNION SELECT '10' UNION SELECT '11'
        UNION SELECT '12' UNION SELECT '13' UNION SELECT '14'
        UNION SELECT '15' UNION SELECT '16' UNION SELECT '17'
        UNION SELECT '18' UNION SELECT '19' UNION SELECT '20'
        UNION SELECT '21' UNION SELECT '22' UNION SELECT '23'
    ) Horas
    LEFT JOIN sgp.balancete_versao D 
    ON SUBSTRING(D.ultimaTransmissao, 12, 2) = Horas.Hora
    AND D.ultimaTransmissao LIKE '2015-10-14%'
    --
) D
GROUP BY D.HORA
ORDER BY 1
```

Comment: Olá obrigado pela resposta, mas está dando erro e não consegui identificar o porque.  `Você tem um erro de sintaxe no seu SQL próximo a 'declare @Horas table
(
    Hora varchar(2)
)`

Comment: Ah, sim seu banco é mysql... editei a resposta veja se ajuda.

Comment: Erro novamente `Coluna 'Horas.Hora' desconhecida em 'field list`

Comment: bom tive que fazer um join com uma tabela do meu banco para fazer o teste... altera a tabela    sgp.balancete_versao para a sua tabela..

Comment: Fiz o teste, rodou mas não mudou nada o desempenho. Continua com 7 segundos de execução.

Comment: Tente pesquisar sobre "sql profiler" para mysql para ver o que esta pesando mais na consulta. se o caso for a tabela CONTATO, veja se é necessário a utilização do LEFT JOIN mude o AND D.CONTATO_DATA LIKE '2015-10-14%' para filtra por year, month e day... year(CONTATO_DATA ) = 2015 ....